# SlyRepeat and ngInclude asking for transclusion on

Tags: angularjs

I need to display a potential huge treeview in my webapplication. During testing I found out that using the standard template rendering method of angular with ngRepeat and ngInclude are not performing enough (it takes around 5 seconds to show the info). Removing binding (because there is no use for it) gave no results.

After some googling I found a module called scalyr https://github.com/scalyr/angular This should really optimize the performance of rendering.

My code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
    {{data.name}}
    <ul>
        <li sly-repeat="data in data.childNodes " ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul>
    <li sly-repeat="data in vm.rows" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

When running this code I get an exception

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [slyRepeat, ngInclude] asking for transclusion on: <li sly-repeat="data in data.childNodes " ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'">
```

Is this fixable? Or is it impossible to run scalyr with ng-Include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with multiple transclusions on the same element, but there's an easy solution:

```
<li sly-repeat="data in data.childNodes ">
<div ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></div>
</li>
```

There is a module that offer [multiple transclusions](https://github.com/mcasimir/angular-multiple-transclusion), but I've never played with it, so I'm not sure that it works.

When you figure out your tree, tell me if the sly-repeat is worth it, as I've got a huge tree to build as well.

Comment: I have 10k nodes and it does not give any boost in performance. Still takes around 3 seconds to build...

Comment: I've got a lot less. Try to find / build a virtual tree, ie one that renders only the part that is visible on the screen. This might be a place to start -https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll

Comment: Thanks, but I think that for 10k nodes, you should still look at a virtual solution.